# How do scriptures mention the physical appearance of Lord Hanuman?

Tags: scripture, hanuman, shloka

In addition to the remarkable features that blend aspects of both a monkey and a human being, what are the intrinsic details of Lord Hanuman's physical appearance as elucidated in scriptures such as complexion, build, and other distinctive features mentioned in dhyana shlokas etc.?

Also, please share pictures that best represent the physical descriptions of Lord Hanuman found in the dhyana shlokas.